# Drake Error: Maximum number of clients reached bad X server connection vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow

Tags: python, vtk, renderer, drake

I am generating new multibody plants in a for loop in my project. If I run it for large number of times, my program crashes with the error:

```
Maximum number of clients reached bad X server connection vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow
```

I think the error is in here:

```
scene_graph.AddRenderer(renderer_name, MakeRenderEngineVtk(RenderEngineVtkParams()))
```

I am not sure how to cleanly remove renderer after using the multi body instance. Any Ideas?

Thanks,

Sarvesh

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't remove renderers from `SceneGraph`. Probably a defect that should be addressed.

Longer answer:

1. It's not just copies of `SceneGraph` that have registered renderers, you also get a copy in each `Context` that gets allocated. So, number of scene graphs + number of contexts is how many OpenGl contexts you're burning through.
2. Now let's explore what you're doing and find out if there's a better way to achieve the same goal.

   - If you're creating lots of `Diagram`s with `MultibodyPlant` and `SceneGraph`, do you need to add a renderer to each one? Your short term solution is to only add the renderer if you're going to use it.
   - The more meta question is why are you creating lots of `Diagrams` with `MultibodyPlant` and `SceneGraph`? The primary justification is that the model in `MultibodyPlant` is slightly different from diagram to diagram (as `MultibodyPlant` is not sufficiently mutable for you).
   - If it turns out that there are really good reasons for *creating* all of the `Diagram`s with renderers in them, how many do you need to keep alive at the same time. Destroying `Context` and `Diagram`'s should reduce usage on the limited resource.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I am doing currently is highly inefficient. I am trying to generate a dataset of various arm poses from different camera angles. In each of scene, an arm is in a fixed pose and I have about 15-20 cameras around it to capture images. Actually, I need even more camera views for the dataset. Ideally, I should be moving one camera around and capture the scene from different views. But I am having multiple no. of cameras in the scene. One reason for this being that I wasn't able to find a way to change camera position after I have welded.

Comment: If I add more number of cameras, program crashes. So, I went with adding less number of cameras in each scene I generate in For loop. I thought that after for loop executes, renderer instance should also be killed but it still crashes. What is a good way to approach my problem? (I need to create dataset of an arm in various poses with different camera views.)

Comment: You can add an arbitrary number of cameras to a scene that all use the same renderer. You just need to add one `RgbdSensor` per camera. Adding lots of cameras should work; You say adding lots of cameras crashes -- is that the error you reported above? If so, it's because they're not using the same renderer.

If you edit your post to give a code snippet of what you're trying to do, I can provide an alternate spelling.